# Как записать эти значения в переменные?

Tags: php

[image: Получаю название команд с сайта(game-tournaments.com/dota2)]

[image: выводятся они вот так]

Расписание команд.
Как мне записать каждое название в отдельную переменную?
Допустим Clutch в $a1, IG в $a2, Secret в $a3 и так далее

Answer (score 0):

Не вдаваясь в тайный смысл внедрения десятка переменных там, где напрашивается использование массива, вы можете использовать варианты, приведенные ниже:

**1. использование`$$`**

```
$c1data = ['Glutch', 'IG', 'Secret'];

foreach($c1data as $idx => $v){
    $n = "a".($idx + 1);
    $$n = $v;
}

print_r([$a1, $a2, $a3]);
```

**2. использование [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)**

```
$vars = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];
extract(array_combine($vars, $c1data));

print_r([$b1, $b2, $b3]);
```